# Property kept under base change and composition is preserved by products

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, schemes

The following is true? Why?

Let $P$ be a property of morphisms preserved under base change and composition. Let $X\to Y$ and $X'\to Y'$ be morphisms of $S$-schemes with property $P$.
Then the unique morphism $X\times_S X' \to Y\times_S Y'$ has property $P$.

Comment: Of course this has nothing to do with schemes.

Comment: Thank you for the nice hint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes this is true.

The canonical morphism $X\times_S X'\to Y\times_S Y'$ is the composition of $X\times_S X'\to Y\times_S X'$ and $Y\times_S X'\to Y\times_S Y'$. The latter verify property P because they are obtained by base change (the first one is $X\to Y$ base changed to $Y\times_S X'$, the second one is similar). As P is stable by composition, your canonical morphism satisfies P.

Comment: I understood. Thank you very much for your kind help.